# R: Making sense of the output of a MCMCglmm

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, bayesian

I performed a MCMCglmm (MCMCglmm package). Here is the summary of this model

```
 Iterations = 3001:12991
 Thinning interval  = 10
 Sample size  = 1000 

 DIC: 211.0108 

 G-structure:  ~Region

       post.mean  l-95% CI u-95% CI eff.samp
Region    0.2164 5.163e-17    0.358     1000

 R-structure:  ~units

      post.mean l-95% CI u-95% CI eff.samp
units    0.5529   0.1808    1.045    449.3

 Location effects: Abondance ~ Human_impact/Fish.sp 

                                   post.mean  l-95% CI  u-95% CI eff.samp  pMCMC    
(Intercept)                         1.335628  0.780363  1.907249    642.4  0.004 ** 
Human_impact                        0.005781 -0.294084  0.347743    876.6  0.914    
Human_impact:Fish.spA. perideraion -0.782846 -1.158798 -0.399131    649.9 <0.001 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

1. Where are the coefficients?
2. post.mean is the mean of the posterior distribution?
3. Can post.mean be somehow considered as the equivalent of the estimates of a standard `lm`
4. What does eff.samp mean?
5. How can I find the degrees of freedom?
6. This model is based on bayesian statistics. Is it correct?

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of 1) `post.mean`, 2) estimate, so yes, 3) sort of, 4) I think it's the sample sized used to calculate the statistic, 5) hum, 6) yes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting the results of a statistical model.  (It's also very much in the "please solve my problem for me" mode ... have you read the MCMCglmm vignette???)

Comment: #4.  `eff.samp` is the effective sample size, it's the number of samples taken adjusted for autocorrelation in the chains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **summary.MCMCglmm**   from `MCMCglmm` package

summary method for class "MCMCglmm". The returned object is suitable for printing with the print.summary.MCMCglmm method.

`DIC`
Deviance Information Criterion

`fixed.formula`
model formula for the fixed terms

`random.formula`
model formula for the random terms

`residual.formula`
model formula for the residual terms

`solutions`
posterior mean, 95% HPD interval, MCMC p-values and effective sample size of fixed (and random) effects

`Gcovariances`
posterior mean, 95% HPD interval and effective sample size of random effect (co)variance components

`Rcovariances`
posterior mean, 95% HPD interval and effective sample size of residual (co)variance components

`cutpoints`
posterior mean, 95% HPD interval and effective sample size of cut-points from an ordinal model

`csats`
chain length, burn-in and thinning interval

`Gterms`
indexes random effect (co)variances by the component terms defined in the random formula

I am under the impression that MCMCglmm does not implement a "true" Bayesian glmmm.  Similarly to the frequentist model, one has g(E(y∣u))=Xβ+Zu and there is a prior required on the dispersion parameter ϕ1 in addition to the fixed parameters β and the "G" variance of the random effect u.

But according to this [MCMCglmm vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf), the model implemented in MCMCglmm is given by g(E(y∣u,e))=Xβ+Zu+e , and it does not involve the dispersion parameter ϕ1. It is not similar to the classical frequentist model.

Degree of Freedom
`mcmcglmm` is a wrapper for the MCMCglmm() function. The wrapper function allows for two variants of two defualt priors on the covariance matrices. The two defaults are InvW for an inverse- Wishart prior, which sets the degrees of freedom parameter equal to the dimension of each covariance matrix, and InvG for an inverse-Gamma prior, which sets the degrees of freedom parameter to 0.002 more than one less than the dimensions of the covariance matrix.